# Walking through an array and sorting

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

OK, so here's the deal: I'm trying to sort teams based on the following criteria (in order):

1. overall record
2. division record
3. head-to-head results
4. points

For items 1, 2, and 4, I can simply pull the data from an SQL database. So when I iterate through the SQL results, I can create the following array:

```
arr[$row['team_id']] => array('overall_wins'  => $row['wins'],
                              'division_wins' => $row['div_wins'],
                              'points'        => $row['pts']);
```

All good so far. The **issue** is when two or more teams have equal overall wins and division wins. In that case, I need to be able to use their **head-to-head** record to break the tie.

So my thought was to iterate through the above array and use temp variables to check if the current `overall_wins` and `division_wins` equal the previous team's values, and then "do something"...use head-to-head record to break the tie.

Now, I can get the head-to-head record between two teams using SQL again, so that's not the problem, but my question is:

**How do I resort my array for display *using* the head-to-head record to break a tie between two teams?**

Let's use the following example:

```
  team_id     overall_wins     division_wins
------------------------------------------
  B           6                6
  A           7                7
  E           6                5
  C           6                6
  G           10               9
  D           4                3
  F           2                0
```

This would at first pass be resorted as:

```
  team_id     overall_wins     division_wins
------------------------------------------
  G           10               9
  A           7                7
  B           6                6
  C           6                6
  E           6                5
  D           4                3
  F           2                0
```

...but let's say **Team C beat Team B head-to-head.** In that case, teams B and C **need to be swapped in the above order.**

I'm not sure how to do this within the confines of PHP arrays alone, without going full-out crazy with entire temporary arrays and whatnot.

Thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Well, what is the schema that allows you to determine the head-to-head result?

Comment: @Jon I compare head-to-head scores of the two teams in question directly in SQL, and get win/loss numbers from that comparison.

Comment: If you just `usort()`, you can call any function/do any database call you like when you realize overall & division wins are the same...

Comment: @Wrikken Good thinking, I completely forgot about `usort()`. I think that's the way to go, thanks! You should add that in an actual answer so I can give you proper credit.

Comment: @praguian: that is an already fixed typo, meant [`usort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) :) (yeah, and you saw that already ;) )

Comment: select out a head-to-head-wins field as a derived/calculated field in the `SELECT` portion, which you can then sort on, e.g. `select team.id, (magic stuff here) AS head_to_head .... ORDER BY overall_wins, division_wins, head_to_head`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use usort

```
  function compareTeams ($a, $b){
            if ($a["overall_wins"] == $b["overall_wins"]){
                if ($a["division_wins"] == $b["division_wins"]){
                   if ($a["head_to_head"] == $b["head_to_head"]){
                      return 0;
                   } else {
                      return $a["head_to_head"] == $b["head_to_head"];
                   }
                } else {
                   return $a["division_wins"] - $b["division_wins"];
                }
            } else {
                return $a["overall_wins"] - $b["overall_wins"];
            }
  }

  usort($arr, "compareTeams");
```

$arr will now be sorted as you require